# If I use the same image on multiple pages, should it be on my sitemap multiple times?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

Following [Google's guide to Image sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en)

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
   <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
   </image:image>
 </url> 
</urlset>`

If let's say I use `ford.jpg` on a broad `/car-manufacturers.html` and then again on `/ford.html`

Should I list the same image twice in my sitemap, in each of those two URLs? Otherwise which one should it go on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should list it once for each URL that the image is associated with. Since users will see the image associated with both pages, it makes sense for scrapers/bots to see the image associated with both pages.